# Why is the "waiting" length so long on my Ajax call? (Chrome Network Panel)

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, jquery, knockout.js

I have a few ajax calls on a page that request some json content.  On all these calls, I am getting a significant wait time on the response completing. For each of these calls, there is a "waiting" period of a few seconds in the call as shown in Chrome Network panel below. I have attached a picture:

[image: Waiting On the Ajax Call - screenshot 1]

I am not really sure what is causing that, as I did some benchmarking on the php code that is querying the database, and according to that, the call for the query and processing the json to send back is running in 0.001 seconds or so.

So, is this just a network latency thing? Is this a problem where I am not doing the database query correctly? Maybe I'm flooding the maximum connections per browser window? No idea. The other requests are moving just as slowly, so it seems like it could be something consistent.

Here is another photo of the rest of the requests timing (with the other main ajax call taking just as much time as the get_usergames_simple call:
[image: All the requests]

For reference, here is the ajax call:

```
self.getGamesContent = function()
{
  var userID = "<?php echo $userID; ?>";

  var post_data = {
    userID: userID
  };

  $.post("https://mydomain.com/games/get_usergames_simple/", post_data, function(result)
  {
    var json = $.parseJSON(result);

    var mappedGames = $.map(json.games, function(item) {
      return new GameItem(item)
    });
    self.gameitems(mappedGames);
  });
};
```

And here is the php code in the controller running the query:

```
$userID = $this->input->post('userID');
$this->benchmark->mark('code_start');

$userGames = $this->cache->model('games', 'getGamesSimpleByUserID', array($userID), 120); // keep for 2 minutes

$returnString = "{";

$returnString .= '"user_id": "' . $userID . '",';

$gameCount = 0;

$returnString .= '"games": [';
foreach ($userGames as $ug)
{
  $returnString .= "{";
  $returnString .= '"user_id" : "' . $userID . '",';
  $returnString .= '"game_id" : "' . $ug->GameID . '",';
  $returnString .= '"game_name" : "' . $ug->GameName . '",';
  $returnString .= '"game_image" : "' . $ug->GameImage . '",';
  $returnString .= '"description" : "' . htmlspecialchars($ug->GameDescription) . '",';
  $returnString .= '"genre_id" : "' . $ug->GameGenreCatID . '",';
  $returnString .= '"genre_name" : "' . $ug->GameGenreName . '",';
  $returnString .= '"publisher_id" : "' . $ug->GamePublisherID . '",';
  $returnString .= '"publisher_name" : "' . $ug->GamePublisherName . '",';
  $returnString .= '"developer_id" : "' . $ug->GameDeveloperID . '",';
  $returnString .= '"developer_name" : "' . $ug->GameDeveloperName . '",';
  $returnString .= '"active_flag" : "' . $ug->GameIsActive . '",';
  $returnString .= '"create_date" : "' . $ug->GameCreateDate . '",';
  $returnString .= '"remove_date" : "' . $ug->GameRemoveDate . '",';
  $returnString .= '"last_update_date" : "' . $ug->GameLastUpdateDate . '",';
  $returnString .= '"user_syncing_game" : "' . $ug->UserSyncingGame . '"';
  $returnString .= "},";
  $gameCount++;
}

if ($gameCount > 0)
  $returnString = substr($returnString, 0, strlen($returnString) - 1);

$returnString .= "]}";


$this->benchmark->mark('code_end');

//echo $this->benchmark->elapsed_time('code_start', 'code_end');

echo $returnString;
```

Comment: Is there anything slow in controller's constructor?

Comment: That's a great question! I hadn't thought of that... Let me do some bench-marking there and get back to you.

Comment: Why no `json_encode()` instead of string concatenations?

Comment: @f_martinez That is totally the problem! Can you answer the question so i can select you as the correct answer?

Comment: @complex857 Can you point me in the right direction on a tutorial or guide for json_encode in this situation? I like having the names coming back from the ajax calls with underscores, but the data structure coming back from the model is camel case. Is this just a dumb mixing of naming conventions?

Comment: @janson0: Simply building up the arrays with proper keys and then json_encode() could work. As it stands a single `"` in any of your data will break the output. I would build some presenter object that would know how to format a response. Its more easily testable, reusable without copy-and-paste. Also, if you only doing camelCase to snake_case you can create simple automatism to generate keys.

Comment: Ok thanks man. There are a lot of moving parts right now, but I will definitely give that a shot for this function first and then hopefully expand it out into the rest of the application.  I am doing the above pretty frequently throughout the app, so it would serve me well to shore that up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely there are some slow actions in the controller's constructor.

It's much better to use built-in profiler in Codeigniter:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/profiling.html