# php script takes much time to load

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I've made a web site using **Codeigniter** and I'm facing the issue related with speed.

All other functionality is much faster but I don't know why it takes too much time to load.

Well Only one query will perform for that operation but waiting time is too much high.

[image]

This issue is occurred first time when website is load.

// **Controller**

```
function hardwareFolder($uId){
    $Folder = $this->System_model->get_folder_category_id($uId);
    $menu = [
        [
            'id' => 'all',
            'pId' => '1',
            'name' => _('All'),
            'icon' => base_url('images/directory_icon.gif'),
            'isParent' => true,
            'checked' => true,
            'nocheck' => true,
            'open' => true,
            'dirlevel' => 'main',
            'dirType' => 'all',
        ],
        [
            'id' => $Folder[0]['c_type_id'],
            'pId' => $Folder[0]['c_type_pid'],
            'name' => 'Unfiled',
            'icon' => base_url('images/unfield.png'),
            'isParent' => true,
            'checked' => true,
            'nocheck' => true,
            'open' => true,
            'dirlevel' => 'main',
            'dirType' => 'unfiled',
        ],
        [
            'id' => $Folder[1]['c_type_id'],
            'pId' => $Folder[1]['c_type_pid'],
            'name' => _('Shared'),
            'icon' => base_url('images/sharedir.png'),
            'isParent' => true,
            'checked' => true,
            'nocheck' => true,
            'open' => true,
            'dirlevel' => 'main',
            'dirType' => 'shared',
        ],
    ];
    return $this->output
        ->set_content_type('application/json')
        ->set_output(json_encode($menu));
}
```

// **Model**

```
function get_folder_category_id($uid){
     $q_s_type = "SELECT c_type_id,c_type_pid,c_type_name " .  
                    "FROM `codeigniter_system_category_type` " .  
                    "   WHERE `c_type_pid` = 0 " . 
                          "AND `c_type_name` = 'Others' " . 
                          "AND `c_module` = 'System' " . 
                          "AND `c_created_userID` = ".$uid . 
                    " UNION SELECT c_type_id,c_type_pid,c_type_name ". 
                    "    FROM `codeigniter_system_category_type` " .
                           "WHERE `c_type_pid` = 0 " . 
                               "AND `c_type_name` = 'Shared' " . 
                               "AND `c_module` = 'System' " .
                               "AND `c_created_userID` = ".$uid;

     return $this->db->query($q_s_type)->result_array();
 }
```

Script call with Ajax.

Comment: Have you tested the query using for example `EXPLAIN`? And have you verified that the query really is the problem?

Comment: share more information. Is this in some kind of loop? How many records are being displayed?

Comment: @jeroen I've tested this query and in mysql and it will takes only 0.00007 sec.

Comment: @Akintunde007 There is no loop, It just call from ajax and here fire only one query and return Json.

Comment: My suggestion to you is check functions you use and their compatibility with your framework and php version. I had faced same problem long time ago with php and after checking some functions I found it's cause some problems.

Comment: Let me check @MouradKaroudi

Comment: Try feeding your query to https://explain.depesz.com/ and feeding the output of that to https://mariadb.org/explain_analyzer/analyze/

Comment: does your connection is with 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' ?

Comment: @AhmedSunny Yes Currently I'm using my localhost, But On server it takes much more time to load while first time (34 sec).

Comment: try '127.0.0.1' on local and see if it changes anything

Comment: What do you see when you set the Network tab to view all activity and not just XHR? It could be the initial load is being blocked by the loading of other assets - i.e. javascript, css.

Comment: and check this also . probably duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15451732/why-is-the-waiting-length-so-long-on-my-ajax-call-chrome-network-panel

Comment: Ok, just for testing purposes can you save the query result then remove the query statement and return the saved query result (to avoid hitting the database) ... this way we can narrow down the problem. conversely, you could also use the benchmarking functionality of CI: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/benchmark.html

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am very much wrong, the only thing that change sin those two `SELECT` statements is the check of the value of `c_type_name`

If so, you can simplify that `UNION`, and lose the second `SELECT`,  by changing from

```
function get_folder_category_id($uid){
 $q_s_type = "SELECT c_type_id,c_type_pid,c_type_name " .  
                "FROM `codeigniter_system_category_type` " .  
                "   WHERE `c_type_pid` = 0 " . 
                      "AND `c_type_name` = 'Others' " . 
                      "AND `c_module` = 'System' " . 
                      "AND `c_created_userID` = ".$uid . 
                " UNION SELECT c_type_id,c_type_pid,c_type_name ". 
                "    FROM `codeigniter_system_category_type` " .
                       "WHERE `c_type_pid` = 0 " . 
                           "AND `c_type_name` = 'Shared' " . 
                           "AND `c_module` = 'System' " .
                           "AND `c_created_userID` = ".$uid;

 return $this->db->query($q_s_type)->result_array();
}
```

to (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16240041/sql-search-multiple-values-in-same-field)

```
function get_folder_category_id($uid){
 $q_s_type = "SELECT c_type_id,c_type_pid,c_type_name " .  
                "FROM `codeigniter_system_category_type` " .  
                "   WHERE `c_type_pid` = 0 " . 
                      "AND `c_type_name` IN ('Others', 'Shared') " . 
                      "AND `c_module` = 'System' " . 
                      "AND `c_created_userID` = ".$uid;

 return $this->db->query($q_s_type)->result_array();
}
```